# Server Connection in Mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb

I have a remote server with Mongodb 64 bit installed and left the mongod running. I am testing to connect with it from home. Using the following connection string C#:

```
connectionString = "mongodb://Administrator:mypassword@x.x.x.x:27017"
```

The connection failed with the following error:

```
Unable to connect to server x.x.x.x:27017: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond x.x.x.x:27017
```

Do I need to have configuration on my server? Or in my connection string?

Comment: Try to ping this server on this port. Maybe you should unlock port in server security. The mongodb works in localhost?

Comment: @NorbertPisz The mongodb's default allows localhost connection right? And if so how to configure my mongodb in the remote server to allow connection unlocally? Thanks mate, I am actually newby for these things.

Comment: I am actually able to establish connection locally in my server but using another machine to connect to this server failed the connection.

Comment: Maybe try to configure ports. Like this http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/configure-linux-iptables-firewall/

Comment: @Wao are you able to get solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem except I can connect from localhost but can't connect from the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasnt able to connect to a remote MongoDB with a connectionstring either. The way I got it working is a bit more verbose, but assuming you tried to do

```
var client = new MongoClient(connectionString);
```

then this could work instead:

```
var client = new MongoClient(
new MongoClientSettings
{
 Credentials = new[]
 {
   MongoCredential.CreateCredential("Databasename","Administrator", "mypassword")
 },
 Server = new MongoServerAddress("x.x.x.x", 27017)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this by binding

```
bind_ip = 0.0.0.0
```